# Duda sobre i2c en CCS compiler

Tags: c, ccs, pic

tengo una duda sobre el protocolo i2c programando en CCS Compiler con un sensor en concreto.

Para sintetizar al máximo os pongo un ejemplo que aparece en el datasheet del sensor para obtener datos del mismo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y a continuación os presento el código en CCS:

```
 #include <18f2550.h>
 #fuses   HSPLL,NOWDT,NOPROTECT,NOLVP,NODEBUG,USBDIV,PLL5,CPUDIV1,VREGEN
 #USE     delay(clock=48000000)
 #use i2c(Master,Fast,sda=PIN_B0,scl=PIN_B1)

 #include <usb_cdc.h>


 void main() {

 i2c_start();
 i2c_write(0x54);
 i2c_write(0x00);
 i2c_write(0x89);
 i2c_write(0x54);
 i2c_write(0x00);
 i2c_write(0x09);
 i2c_stop();

 usb_cdc_init();
 usb_init();

       while(TRUE) {

           delay_ms(10);
           i2c_write(0x54);
           i2c_write(0x03);
           i2c_write(0x55);

           int8 RM=i2c_read(1);
           int8 RL=i2c_read(1);
           unsigned char GM=i2c_read(1);
           unsigned char GL=i2c_read(1);
           unsigned char BM=i2c_read(1);
           unsigned char BL=i2c_read(1);
           unsigned char IM=i2c_read(1);
           unsigned char IL=i2c_read(0);
           i2c_stop();

           usb_task();


               if (usb_enumerated()) {


                     printf( usb_cdc_putc,"%d", (RM << 8) | RL );                        
                     printf(usb_cdc_putc, "\f ");

               }

       }

  }
```

Me gustaría saber si encontráis algún fallo ya que la recogida de datos me parece un poco aleatoria y no se con certeza si he programado bien tal y como aparece en el datasheet.

Os adjunto el PDF del sensor por si alguien quisiera ayudar y ahondar más en la programación de este.   ----> [Link del Datasheet del sensor](https://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/s11059-02dt_etc_kpic1082e.pdf)